# How to count exact text contain in string [Excel]

Tags: excel, count, countif

I already use these below formula to count exact text contain in string but still formula wrongly counted it. For example, i would like to count "ZIKA" test code in table, the answer should be two. But the formula count ZIKA2 as ZIKA also. How to ignore ZIKA2 from count it?

### TEST

- HS2, CCAL, EGFR, AFB
- ZIKA, AG21
- PPB, ZIKA2
- ZIKA, AG21

I already try these formulas:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(FIND("ZIKA",F:F))))
```

and also

```
=COUNTIF(F:F,"ZIKA")
```

Comment: In that case you need regex I think. Unless Zika is always on the left of a comma?

Comment: ZIKA is randomly not always on the left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could count exact zika, and comma-separated vriations

`=COUNTIF(F:F,"ZIKA")+COUNTIF(F:F,"ZIKA,*")+COUNTIF(F:F,"*, ZIKA")+COUNTIF(F:F,"*, ZIKA,*")`

Comment: it still count ZIKA2 as ZIKA

Comment: thx @AlexandrX , your formula finally solved my problem. thx mate and everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex, it may need a helpercolumn. I have not tested it that much yet.
Press ALT + F11 to open VBA editor.
Click Insert -> module and copy paste the code below.

```
Function Regex(Cell, Search)
    Dim RE As Object

    Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    RE.Pattern = "(\b" & Search & "\b)"
    RE.Global = True
    RE.IgnoreCase = True
    Set Matches = RE.Execute(Cell)

    For Each res In Matches
        Regex = Regex & "," & res
    Next res
    Regex = Mid(Regex, 2)
End Function
```

It will return "ZIKA" if it finds ZIKA in the cell you run it on.
And then you just count the ZIKAs in the helper column.

Updated with a new code that you can change the search in.
Use it with `=regex(A1, "ZIKA")`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume your data follow this format

> xxx, yyy, zzz
>   space after comma

You may need to split your formula into 3 parts

```
=COUNTIF(F:F,"ZIKA,*")+COUNTIF(F:F,"*, ZIKA")+COUNTIF(F:F,"ZIKA")
```

The first part will count those start with **ZIKA**, second part count those end with **ZIKA**, last we should count those only with **ZIKA**